# Can I limit source IP to a GCP Load Balancer created by Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes 1.4.5 cluster running on GKE that I would like to put into test.  It accepts HTTPS using an Ingress as below

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: keycloak-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: mysecret
  backend:
    serviceName: keycloak-https-service
    servicePort: 443
```

Whilst in test, I want to limit the source IPs that can access my cluster.  Because the Load Balancer converts the source IP of all incoming traffic into local IP addresses, the Google Cloud firewall cannot limit this traffic.  Is there a way I can limit traffic going into the load balancer?

I understand this is strictly an GCE question, but there may be a solution that Kubernetes may offer.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at a pipeline:

> GCE L7 LB -> vm:nodePort -> pods

The traffic going:

> GCE L7 LB -> your vms

should come from 130.211.0.0/22  as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#fundamentals. You should already have a firewall rule for that. 
The traffic going:

> vms -> containers

should come from your vm ips. You can't regulate who talks the the lb, you can regulate who talks to the nodes.

Unfortunately because of the described situation, this doesn't work for HTTP LB. It will work for L3/L4 LB, because you get the source ip of your actual client in the packet that ends up at the vm: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/load-balancer/#annotation-to-modify-the-loadbalancer-behavior-for-preservation-of-source-ip

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I've fallen back to L4 (I think!) using Service

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  

I've fallen back to L4 (I think!) using Service type LoadBalancer, but I'm still loosing source IP.  Looking at the GCP loadbalancing, it now only has a Forwarding Rule, going to a Target Pool which feeds into the VMs.  Is there a better way on GCP?

`    kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: keycloak-https-service
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      externalIPs:
      - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      ports:
      - port: 443
        targetPort: 8443
        name: https
      selector:
        app: keycloak-pod`

Comment: Source IP for sessions as seen in the target container will not be the original source IP of the client. This is the default behavior as of Kubernetes v1.5. However, starting in v1.5, an optional beta feature has been added that will preserve the client Source IP for GCE/GKE environments.

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Armor product enables you to restrict access to a Load Balancer using an IP whitelist. This product might have been introduced since the OP asked the question. I've used Cloud Armor to IP restrict load balanced traffic to Kubernetes Ingress.

https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#ip_address_allow_list_and_deny_list_rules_in_a_security_policy